# Executing classes from an existing php script from a file in a new subfolder

Tags: php, class, include

I quite a large php script that I am adapting and adding to, the script currently executes from the root folder, I need to adapt it so that I can add additional sub folders and include and run this script alongside the new code and subfolder.

I have already changed all the includes and require_once to absolute so they can be run from files in new subfolders. I just need to find a way to make the classes run now.

Does any one have any ideas as to how to approach this?
An example of the class code is as follows:

```
\Script\Addons::register('content_editor', 'story_detector');

$escapeObj = new \Script\Escape();
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you talking about PSR-4 Autoloading?

Comment: yes I beleive I am.

Comment: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/ Then don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: ok thanks I`ll take a look

Comment: (`beleive` - I'm quite positive it's _believe_) `I quite a large php script` I'm at a loss how to interpret `quite` here.

Comment: Ok the script comprises of around  2000 files and the classes are currently set up to execute only from files in the root of the script. I wish to make a change to allow the classes to run from various new subfolders therefore allowing me to integrate various scripts into this one.